# Angular 5 - Validate input field with default value

Tags: angular, validation

I have form with input field with default value. I want to add validation for that field to have exactly 5 characters.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" maxlength="5" ngModel 
    #number="ngModel" name="number" value="{{data.number}}" class="form-control">
</td>
```

The problem is that I cannot get that default value in order to validate as the value of input shows mi empty string "". If I change that value the proper value is visible. Is there a way to use validator in this case ?

SOLUTION:

```
    <td>
    <input type="text" maxlength="5" [(ngModel)]="data.number" 
    #number name="number" class="form-control">
</td>
```

Comment: `minlength = 5`

Comment: But on start (when I have default value) my value from input is equals "". So I will have error

Comment: If I add required it will allow to insert no value.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ReactiveForms` module and simply add the desired validators. In your case something like this would work:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      myInput: new FormControl('defaultValue',[Validators.minLength(5),Validators.maxLength(5)])
})
```

Template:

```
<form name="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <label>
    <div>My input</div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="myInput" [ngClass]="{'error': myForm.invalid}">
  </label>
</form>
```

[Here's a working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3e3ag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)